# Undefined method '+@' for String, not the whitespace issue

Tags: ruby, string, methods, undefined

I have a program that is meant to take two arrays and create a single string out of their contents, in the form of `A[0] + B[0] + A[1] + B[1]`...et alia. The problem is this - strangely, the `<<` operator seems to work correctly for appending A's first element, but not after that. To be precise:

```
complexKey = "#JohnSmith_"
n = 0

#isbns = [2,3]
versions = [1,1]

isbns.each do |isbn| 
complexKey << "#{versions[n]}_" 
n++ #an iterator is a crude tool, but I need it to deal with iterating through multiple arrays simultaneously
complexKey << "#{isbn}_"
end
```

The end result of this is meant to be "JohnSmith_1_2_1_3_". However, the problem is this: When the code is run, I get an error:

```
'undefined method '+@' for "JohnSmith_1_":String(noMethodError)
```

I looked this up, and it usually seems to be to do with not having enough whitespace before the concatenation operator, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Any ideas?

Comment: `+@` is an unary plus commonly used with numbers, like `+1.0` as positive one. I fail to see where are you using it in the code you supplied, in fact I only see an increment that can't collide this way. Besides, you might as well use `each_with_index` and avoid that hackery with `n`: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index

Comment: You could use `versions.zip(isbns).flatten.join('_')` instead of a loop.

Comment: @matt `isbn` is assigned as a block variable. It is `isbns` that is not defined.

Comment: There is no `++` operator in Ruby, your expression is intrepeted as `n + ( + complexKey << "#{..}" )`, hence you get the error.

Comment: As a note you can do things like `[ isbns, versions ].transpose.each do |isbn, version|` if you want to iterate over both at once. `n` is not necessary if you have the right data structure for the `each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a thing like `++` in ruby. Use `n += 1` instead.

This code:

```
n++
complexKey << "#{isbn}_"
```

Is interpreted as:

```
n + +(comlexKey << "#{isbn}_")
```

`<<` operator on string returns a string, hence next step is `+'some_string'` which is equivalent to `'some_string'.send(:@+)` - hence the error.